# customer_id is null Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

i am creating a spring boot task project. task project consist of customer and task table.one customer has one task.i made the relationship one to one i attached below.i ran into the problem with customer_id is null.

**Customer**

```
    @Id
@Column(name = "id", length = 50)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name="fname")
private String fname;

@Column(name="lname")
private String lname;

@Column(name="city")
private String  city;



@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)

private Task task;
```

**Task**

```
 @Id
@Column(name = "task_id", length = 50)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int taskid;

@Column(name="task_name")
private String taskname;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;

@Column(name="complete")
private Boolean complete;

@OneToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;
```

when i tried to create the new task on postman i got the error was

```
{
   
        "taskname" : "dsf",
        "description": "sdfdsf",
        "complete": true,
        "customer_id" : 1


}
```

true,,1,asfff,jofin

customer_id is null

**TaskController**

```
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private Taskservice taskservice;

    @GetMapping("/gettaskall")
    public Iterable<Task>getStudents()
    {
        return taskservice.listAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    private long saveBook(@RequestBody Task task)
    {
        taskservice.saveOrUpdate(task);
        return  task.getTaskid();
    }

    @PutMapping("/edit/{id}")
    private Task update(@RequestBody Task task)
    {
        taskservice.saveOrUpdate(task);
        return task;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    private void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
        taskservice.delete(id);
    }



}
```

**Taskservice**

```
public class Taskservice {

    @Autowired
    private TaskResository repo;

    public Iterable<Task> listAll() {
        return this.repo.findAll();
    }

    //saving a specific record by using the method save() of CrudRepository
    public void saveOrUpdate(Task task)
    {
        repo.save(task);
    }

    public Task getTaskById(int id)
    {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }


    public void update(Task task, int id)
    {
        repo.save(task);
    }

    public void delete(int id)
    {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }




}
```

Comment: can you provide the controller method and the service method.

Comment: i updatedd can you check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things:

1. your attribute name is customer while the json property you are sending is customer_id. Without additional configuration, jackson won't understand that.
2. your Customer is marked with @JsonIgnore, meaning that even if the above was fixed, it potentially would not work because that annotation basically means "don't serialize/deserialize anything with this attribute name".

As a third recommendation, do not use JPA entities as 'view' objects - this can cause many unwanted side effects. Always use a DTO to map data in/out your controller.

Comment: can you write code for fix

Answer (score 0):

As best practice don't use an entity for data transferring and use another `bean` or `dto` class to do that. the case i think due to fact that you have annotate `private Customer customer;` as `@JsonIgnore` the getter is not called. therefore, that variable is still not initialized. if you use another bean to transfer data you have to call the getter of `private Customer customer;`. please try it.